# Horseshoes of zephyr and difficult terrain

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Ok so I have a player who wants to get some *horseshoes of a zephyr*.

> *Horseshoes of a Zephyr:* These four iron shoes are affixed like normal horseshoes. They allow a horse to travel without actually touching the ground. The horse must still run above (always around 4 inches above) a roughly horizontal surface. This means that nonsolid or unstable surfaces can be crossed, and that movement is possible without leaving tracks on any sort of ground. The horse moves at its normal base land speed.

My player is asserting that the shoes thus negate difficult terrain, but I don't think that the description indicates they would negate difficult terrain underwater, or caused by a spell like *entangle*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Horseshoes of a zephyr* negates difficult terrain when you, as DM, determine that not touching the ground would do so. Being in water, certainly not. A wet surface, or water only a couple inches deep? That would be ignored thanks to being ~4 in. above that surface. *Entangle*’s vines reach up, but *grease* just covers a surface. And so on. It is up to you on a case-by-case basis, and should sometimes have the effect of eliminating difficult terrain, but not always. If it caused you to always ignore difficult terrain, it would say so (and some magic does have that effect).

Unfortunately, generally speaking, difficult terrain does not have some kind of “reach” or “height” statistic defining this. You have to rely on the descriptions of the terrain and make a judgment—and not all forms of difficult terrain even offer enough description to suggest an answer one way or another. This is an unfortunate shortcoming of the rules, but it’s just something that you, as DM, will have to deal with (even if you banned *horseshoes of a zephyr*, low-altitude flight often prompts the same kinds of questions).